# Please How to convert this raw sql query to laravel eloquent or query builder?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello Laravel Developers, Good day. Please how can I convert a raw sql query to laravel query builder or eloquent ORM.

I have the following models:

relationships

Model Server

```php
  public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'server_users')->withPivot('spam','inbox');;
    }

    public function users_cancellation()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'server_user_cancellations')->withPivot('spam','inbox');;
    }
```

Model User

```php
   public function servers(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Server::class, 'server_users');
    }

    public function servers_cancellation(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Server::class, 'server_user_cancellations');
    }
```

tables

User

```php
   $table->id();
            $table->string('full_name');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->boolean('is_active')->default(true);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
```

Server

```php
    Schema::create('servers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name')->default('SM');
            $table->ipAddress('ip')->unique();
            $table->string('username')->default('root');
            $table->boolean('is_active')->default(true);
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Server_user_cancellations

```php
   Schema::create('server_user_cancellations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignIdFor(Server::class)->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete()->cascadeOnUpdate();
            $table->foreignIdFor(User::class)->constrained()->cascadeOnUpdate()->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->boolean('spam')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('inbox')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Server_users

```php
  Schema::create('server_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignIdFor(Server::class)->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete()->cascadeOnUpdate();
            $table->foreignIdFor(User::class)->constrained()->cascadeOnUpdate()->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->boolean('spam')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('inbox')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

i want to convert this raw sql query to laravel eloquent or query builder?

```php
if ($request->wantsJson()) {
  $servers = DB::select('
  SELECT 
    s.name,
    s.id,
    s.ip,
    (SELECT count(id) 
      FROM server_user_cancellations 
      where server_id = s.id and user_id=?
    ) as exist
  FROM servers s
  WHERE s.id IN
    (SELECT  distinct server_id from server_users  where user_id=?)
    AND s.is_active=true
    AND s.is_installed=true
    AND s."deleted_at" is null', 
  [auth()->id(), auth()->id()]
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from query i assume `Server` can belong to many `User`s and `User` can have many `Server`s, and both has many `ServerUserCancellation`, so you need servers for current user with cancellations existence flag

first define [relations](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships) that fits your database schema

```php
// Server model
public function cancellations(){
  return $this->hasMany(ServerUserCancellation::class);
}

public function users(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}

// User model
public function servers(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Server::class);
}
```

now you can [count](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) cancellations and filter servers [which has](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) current user according to `users` relation

```php
$baseFilters = [
  'is_active' => true,
  'is_installed' => true,  
];
$result = Server::where($basicFilters)
  ->whereNull('deleted_at')
  ->whereHas('users', function($query){
      $query->where('user_id', auth()->id());
    })
  ->withCount(['cancellations as exists' => function($query){
      $query->where('user_id', auth()->id();
    }])
  ->select(['id', 'ip', 'name'])
  ->get();

//result strucure will be looking like this
array(
  [
    'id': 1,
    'ip': '127.0.0.1',
    'name': 'server 1 name',
    'exists': 0  
  ], 
  ...
)
```

---

to make controller cleaner there is mechanism of [soft deleting](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#soft-deleting) to skip `whereNull('deleted_at')` for each `Server` query and [scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#local-scopes) to make code easy to read

```php
// Server model
class Server extends Model {
  use SoftDeletes;

  public function scopeActive($query){
    return $query->where('is_active', true);
  }

  public function scopeInstalled($query){
    return $query->where('is_installed', true);
  }

  // ... other model code
}
```

and code will look like this

```php
$result = Server::active()
  ->installed()
  ->whereHas('users', function($query){
      $query->where('user_id', auth()->id());
    })
  ->withCount(['cancellations as exists' => function($query){
      $query->where('user_id', auth()->id();
    }])
  ->select(['id', 'ip', 'name'])
  ->get();
```

Comment: i update my question above please help,i appreciate your help thanks

Comment: @housnah and what help do you need? To paste your relation names into code I've provided?) Your code seems fine

Comment: I am grateful for your help , just combining select and withCount doesn't work because i should do withCount after select just like the document in link below https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#relationship-counting-and-custom-select-statements